Capacitor SplashScreen is black or white before showing (ios)
How can i configure this capacitor plugin, so that backgroundColor actually have the effect of changing the color of the background? Right now the App opens with a black screen a second or two, and then the 3000ms duration of the splashscreen kicks in, which comfirms that the config file have some effect.
(capacitor.config.json)
{
  "plugins": {
    "SplashScreen": {
      "launchShowDuration": 3000,
      "launchAutoHide": true,
      "launchFadeOutDuration": 3000,
      "backgroundColor": "#DF993E" // Dosnt change anything
    }
  }
}

(https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/splash-screen)
